# How to add 2 variable rewrite rule?

Tags: url-rewriting, gallery, slug

I want to end up with url structure for galleries like the one below ;

http://myurl.com/gallery-name/gallery-item-name

as you see there will be two variables.

I separated templates like content-default and content-gallery.. So far it's OK. But what should i do to open a single gallery element page when user goes to this link?

Comment: The actual url is gonna be like : http://myurl.com/gallery-name/?item=gallery-item-name and turns into this : http://myurl.com/gallery-name/gallery-item-name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here is my final solution.. Wordpress already has this opportunity for attached galleries.. Check if your theme already has a file called `attachment.php` otherwise create one and copy the content of `single.php` and modify.

This solution does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a rewrite rule to parse the URL and pull out the value of `gallery-name` and `gallery-item-name`. This will be tricky as there is nothing to distinguish your proposed URL structure from a hierarchical page structure. If you can throw in something that is always the same for all gallery URLs like `/gallery/<gallery-name>/<gallery-item-name>/`.

Once you have a rewrite rule in place you can hook into the [`template_include` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include), check if your two variables are set and then tell WordPress to include your gallery template.

Shiba Shake has a good tutorial on galleries with custom permalinks
http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-permalink-add

Comment: Can't we write an if condition just like if(has_category('gallery')) {add this rule} ?
`'(has_category=='gallery')(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&gallery_item=$matches[2]`

Comment: It wouldn't work because `has_category()` checks against a `$post` and the rewrite rules are added way before we even know what `$post` the request is dealing with. The job of rewrite rules is to parse out variables from a URL that get sent to `WP_Query` which determines which posts should be displayed.